# How can I tweak this split-tar-gz-archive script?

Tags: command-line, tar, archive

I came across this [shell script](http://www.informatik-vollmer.de/software/split-tar.php) that can be used to split an entire directory across multiple compressed files.

I am interested in making a minor tweak to this script. Lets say I have n GB of files in a directory. I do not want the contents of a particular folder to be split across multiple tar files but inside the same file. I want the n MB folder to be fit within a single compressed file and the remaining (n GB -n MB) split across multiple files.

I am not sure whether it is possible with this script. I was looking forward to some suggestions. Though the script has been well documented, it is quite complex to understand for me

Comment: Perhaps you could use a strategy that involves handling the special cases you mentioned separately and then running the script on the rest of the files. This would take the form of some type of filter in the shell script to ignore 'special case' folders and should be a minor change to `emit_dir_parts*.

Comment: @Sai Have you solved this problem or lost interest in this question? As it is 5+ years old it would have been about EOL Ubuntu 12.04 or earlier EOL version. I'm on a project to flag such unanswered questions as `not reproducible` but you may write an answer if you have one. I know that modern day `tar` can split an archive over multiple files and wonder if this question is unnecessary today?

Comment: I solved this problem but I don't remember how I resolved it.